# $ n \in \mathbb N_1, 2000\ |\ n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4). $ Find the smallest $ n $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the expression consists of 5 consecutive integers $\to$ divisible by $5!=120$. And as the expression is divisible by 2000, $ LCM(120, 2000) = 6000 \to 6000\ |\ n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4) $

And I'm lost.

**Hint from the book:**

> Prove that one of the factors is divisible by 125 then n $ \geqslant $ 121.

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to follow the hint?

Comment: @lulu Sincerely, I couldn't understand how this hint could help me, but with the answer below it became crystal clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint from the book seems really good.

There is always going to be exactly one factor between $n,(n+1),(n+2),(n+3),(n+4)$ that is a multiple of $5$, and since $2000=2^{4}5^{3}$ that factor needs to be a multiple of $5^3=125$.

In order to have a factor that is a multiple of $125$ we must have that $n$ is at least $121$.

The condition that the product be a multiple of $2^4$ seems easier to accomplish, so we just test with $121$ and notice we can only extract $2$ from $122$ and $4$ from $124$ so it doesn't work. However with $122$ we can extract $2$ from $122$ and $4$ from $124$ and $2$ from $126$ so it works. So the answer is $122$.